# SQL Server 2008 web management scripts?

Tags: sql-server-2008, scripting

does anyone know what SQL Server 2008 management scripts exists (except myLittleAdmin)?

Thanks

Clarification: I'm looking for web based management script (which supports SQL Server 2008) other than myLittleAdmin.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

See

- [Something like phpMyAdmin but for SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372641/something-like-phpmyadmin-but-for-sql-server)
- [Free or open source .Net database view/edit tools like phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764539/free-or-open-source-net-database-view-edit-tools-like-phpmyadmin)