# Something like phpMyAdmin but for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, phpmyadmin

I am looking for web based tool like phpMyAdmin, but for SQL Server. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've also found [this product](http://www.mylittleadmin.com/en/welcome.aspx) which seems to support SQL Server

Answer (score 17):

This works and is under active development:
http://www.adminer.org/

Comment: On Debian, Ubuntu:  `apt-cache search adminer`
> `adminer - Web-based database administration tool` `sudo apt-get install adminer`  open browser at `http://localhost/adminer` or whatever host you've installed it on. Works out of the box. Very cool.

Comment: One simple php file, no setup needed, works like a charm. Compares itself to myPhpAdmin and touts better features. Using it on IIS with Sqlsvr 2012. Handles all sorts of databases. Super easy to use. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You could try some thing from the [list](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/partners/msde.mspx) provided by Microsoft. Microsoft also apparently has a [web admin](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1311), but it's rather old from what I can see. I'm interested in this area as well, so please report back on your conclusions.

Comment: Well, web has limited features so I wouldn't suggest this one. Instead of it, if you have money then purchase something really working.

Answer (score 2):

-**THIS MIGHT NOT BE THE ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION**-

if you have sql server managment studio(its free) you can connect to a SQL Server database remotely

Comment: I know and I think the person asked this question also knew. However, with phpmyadmin, you could access the database from any computer. Without the web-based system like that, you will have to install the software on every computer you want to access to the database. Yet, in some cases you also need to add your client ip to the firewall exception on the server. With things like phpmyadmin, you never have to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not want to make self-ad, but definitively [myLittleAdmin](http://www.mylittleadmin.com) is what you're looking for. Note most of the *serious* windows webhosting companies are providing myLittleAdmin as a service to all their customers who use MS SQL databases.