# Enterprise Manager/SSMS Web access

Tags: sql-server

I vaguely recall coming across a free web base app that reproduces some of the functionality of SQL Server Enterprise Mgr or SSMS over the web and am not pressed to find it quickly.

Basically, the immediate functionality that I need is to get a web site up to allow visitors to type sample test data directly into out database tables.

Your suggestions on a free tool would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a free tool made by Microsoft, [Database Manager](http://www.iis.net/download/databasemanager).

If that's not what you meant, you can find some more here (this was asked on Stack Overflow and Server Fault before):

- [Something like phpMyAdmin but for SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372641/something-like-phpmyadmin-but-for-sql-server)
- [PhpMyAdmin for Sql Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/485/phpmyadmin-for-sql-server)