# Is there a free Web UI that will bind to an sql server database and allow basic column filtering and data export?

Tags: sql-server, web-applications

I have been asked to find pre-packaged Web based UI that can be dumped on top of an SQL Server database and allow a non-technical user to browse it. The user must be able to:

- Browse the table data.
- Filter results on a per column basis.
- Save the filters they have applied.
- Export the data they are viewing to excel.
- Has to be free for commercial use.
- There is no need to write or edit the data.

Is there any such software package available?

So far I have looked at [OData Explorer](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/odataexplorer/default.html) but I cannot find a way to save or export filtered data.

**Edit:**
Ideally it should be Microsoft based .Net/Silverlight etc.

Comment: Something phpMyAdmin-ish comes to mind: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3103345/139010 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1372641/139010

Comment: There's plenty of links there for me to view so thanks for that @MattBall. They look like they may be quite technical though. I am looking for a data browser than an admin tool.

Comment: SQL Server Master Data Services would also meet some of the requirements (although not all, hence not placing it as a full answer).  It has a Silverlight-based web UI and comes with SQL Server (64-bit BI/Enterprise).  It runs off its own database though, so you'd need ETL processes to keep everything in sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it does not quite conform to all the requirements above we have elected to use a Excel plugin called [PowerPivot](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/powerpivot.aspx). We can easily create an OData Service that consumes our database and our users can then access the data directly through excel.